# How to connect a button with a function of an external class in PyQt?

Tags: python, class, oop, pyqt

I have a really simple GUI that I wrote with PyQt5, in which a canvas is created with a new class PlotCanvas, and a dummy button is placed.

```
class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.title = 'PyQt5 matplotlib example - pythonspot.com'
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 400
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        m = PlotCanvas(self, width=5, height=4)
        m.move(0,0)

        button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        button.setToolTip('This s an example button')
        button.move(500,0)
        button.resize(140,100)
        self.show()


class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        self.plot()


    def plot(self):
        data = [random.random() for i in range(25)]
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(data, 'r-')
        ax.set_title('PyQt Matplotlib Example')
        self.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The function "plot" inside the class PlotCanvas draws a random curve. I am trying to connect the dummy button to the external function "plot" so that it runs again and the plot is updated with a new curve. I do this by adding

```
button.clicked.connect(PlotCanvas.plot)
```

after the definition of the button.

However, my GUI closes with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MinimalExample_EDIT.py", line 62, in plot
    ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'figure'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `button.clicked.connect(m.plot)`

Comment: That was the solution!! It plot a new curve on my current axes everytime I click the button. The only thing missing is how to delete the previous curve

Comment: You have to reuse the axes, check the _update_canvas of the example provided by matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html

Comment: Thank you! I also found that an easier solution will be to clear the existing axes

```
self.axes.cla()

```

Answer (score -1):

From quick analysis: your problem lies in the fact that `self` is an object of PlotCanvas which does not have `self.figure` property defined, but instead `fig`

`fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)`

so you can try to do instead

`ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)`

in `def plot(self)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! However, I already tried that, and it throws the error
'PlotCanvas' object has no attribute 'fig'

Comment: No. The problem is that by calling the **class** method instead of the instance one, it is then treated as unbound method, making `self` argument not the instance, but the signal argument (which is a bool for `clicked` signals).